# How do I make the other tab content working the same as the active tab?

Tags: javascript, php, tabs

The first tab is working fine but when I copied it and pasted for the content of the other tabs its not working. I have a date input that displays the current date but is editable also the tab content contains table that displays data. When you click on the midterm tab it does not display data inside the table also the date is not displaying the current date which I used with javascript/jquery.

```
 <div class="container">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active" href="#prelim">Prelim</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link" href="#midterm">Midterm</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Tab panes -->
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="prelim" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-inline form-padding">
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <label>Date:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">                          
                                    <input type ="date" id="todays-date" value="" class="form-control" name="date" required>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table id="dtable" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                                <thead class="bg-dark text-light">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="text-center">Student ID</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Student Name</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Status</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rss)): ?>
                                <?php
                                    $studid = $row['student_id'];
                                    $stud = mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from tbl_student where stud_id = '$studid'");
                                    $rs= mysqli_fetch_array($stud);  
                                ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $studid; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $rs['stud_lname'];?>, <?php echo $rs['stud_fname'];?> <?php echo $rs['stud_mname'];?> <?php echo $rs['stud_suffix'];?></td>
                                        <td class="text-center">
                                            <a Title="Present" href='' onclick="this.href='action/actionclass.php?present&classid=<?php echo $classid; ?>&studid=<?php echo $studid;?>&period=Prelim&date='+document.getElementById('todays-date').value"><i class="fas fa-check fa-2x text-success"></i></a>&nbsp;
                                            <a Title="Absent" href='' onclick="this.href='action/actionclass.php?absent&classid=<?php echo $classid; ?>&studid=<?php echo $studid;?>&period=Prelim&date='+document.getElementById('todays-date').value"><i class="fas fa-times fa-2x text-danger"></i></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php $c++; ?>
                                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                                    <?php if(mysqli_num_rows($rss) < 1): ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="3" class="text-center text-danger"><h5>*** EMPTY ***</h5></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php endif;?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

IN THIS SECTION STARTS THE SECOND TAB CONTENT.

```
                    <div id="midterm" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-inline form-padding">
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <label>Date:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">                          
                                    <input type ="date" id="todays-date" value="" class="form-control" name="date" required>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table id="dtable" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                                <thead class="bg-dark text-light">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="text-center">Student ID</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Student Name</th>
                                        <th class="text-center">Status</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rss)): ?>
                                <?php
                                    $studid = $row['student_id'];
                                    $stud = mysqli_query($mysqli,"select * from tbl_student where stud_id = '$studid'");
                                    $rs= mysqli_fetch_array($stud);  
                                ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo $studid; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $rs['stud_lname'];?>, <?php echo $rs['stud_fname'];?> <?php echo $rs['stud_mname'];?> <?php echo $rs['stud_suffix'];?></td>
                                        <td class="text-center">
                                            <a Title="Present" href='' onclick="this.href='action/actionclass.php?present&classid=<?php echo $classid; ?>&studid=<?php echo $studid;?>&period=Midterm&date='+document.getElementById('todays-date').value"><i class="fas fa-check fa-2x text-success"></i></a>&nbsp;
                                            <a Title="Absent" href='' onclick="this.href='action/actionclass.php?absent&classid=<?php echo $classid; ?>&studid=<?php echo $studid;?>&period=Midterm&date='+document.getElementById('todays-date').value"><i class="fas fa-times fa-2x text-danger"></i></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php $c++; ?>
                                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                                    <?php if(mysqli_num_rows($rss) < 1): ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="3" class="text-center text-danger"><h5>*** EMPTY ***</h5></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php endif;?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rss))` it will loop until there are no more rows to fetch.

Then later when you do `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rss))` again it will loop until there are no more rows to fetch but starting from where it left off last time (after the last row).

If that's the issue you should be able to add

`mysqli_data_seek($rss, 0);`

just above your second while loop to tell it to restart from the first row again.

Comment: It worked. Thankyou very much Sir! How about a javascript?


`<script>
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = ("0" + (today.getDate())).slice(-2);
    var mm = ("0" + (today.getMonth() +　1)).slice(-2);
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd ;
    $("#todays-date").attr("value", today);
</script>
`

Comment: Nothing wrong with that javascript that I can see. Is it not doing what you want?

Comment: It should display the current date. It does on the first tab but not on the next tabs.

Comment: `$("#todays-date")` will always return the first matching element. You could change `$("#todays-date")` to `$(".todays-date")` and add `todays-date` to the input's `class` attribute.

Comment: Technically you should never have more than one html element with the same `id` but you can have as many elements with the same `class` as you want.